# If $T$ is an operator, $T$ also an isomorphism, it is true that $T$ is selfadjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and $T:H\longrightarrow H$ be an operator. Moreover, suppose $T$ be an isomorphism. It is true that $T$ is selfadjoint?

If not, there is a relation between be isomorphism and be selfadjoint?

Could anyone help or give some counterexample or refernces?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is rarely the case : for example, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not selfadjoint but is an isomorphism. What is true is that $\left(\varphi^{-1}\right)^* = \left(\varphi^*\right)^{-1}$.

For an endomorphism in an orthonormal basis, the matrix of the asdjoint is the symmetric (transpose) of the matrix of the previous endomorphism.

Comment: Mind, $(\varphi^{-1})^*=(\varphi^*)^{-1}$ is true for invertible operators between arbitrary vector spaces. Of course it doesn't make much sense to talk about self-adjoint operators in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have functional analysis in mind, how about the Fourier transform on $L^2$? It's unitary, but it is not self adjoint- it's inverse is its adjoint.

In fact, if $T$ is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces, then this usually means that it's unitary, so that $T^{-1}=T^*.$ So, you're really asking when is it that $T=T^{-1}.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just another question, if you would answer. Suppose that $T$ is an isomorphism which has a selfadjoint restriction. In this case you could say that $T$ is selfadjoint?

Comment: What do you call a selfadjoint restriction ?

Comment: Look at the matrix in the answer from cmk and restrict it to the first coordinate ...

Comment: @DIdier_ Let $H_1\hookrightarrow H$ and consider. Let $A$ be the operator defined as the restriction of $T$ on $H_1$. Then suppose $A$ is selfadjoint in the usual sense.

Comment: It depends on the conditions on the subspace that you restrict it to. In general, no.

Comment: Thus the answer is no : see my previous example on y answer. On the first coordinate, it is self-adjoint.

Comment: @cmk, what conditions on the subspace should be verified in order to have selfadjointness?

Comment: @C.Bishop since this is a notable deviation from your original question and this comment chain is getting pretty long, you should probably ask this as a separate question.

Comment: It is almost never true I would say. Define $H = H_1 \oplus H_2$. Chose a selfadjoint opetator $T_1 : H_1 \to H_1$ and a no selfadjoint operator $T_2 : H_2 \to H_2$. Then $T_1 \oplus T_2$ is not self adjoint.